# how to create a angular http factory

Tags: angularjs

The http function I have is working fine, it is currently in my controller. I would like to put it a factory so i can inject it some where is if I need to. I know I can reuse the same code somewhere else but i would rather keep everything organized. right now I am not passing the object "newCivil" from the controller to the factory. 
code that currently works in the controller

```
//Post Civil Case
$scope.addCivilCase = function () {
    var newCivil = $scope.newCivil
    $http.post('/api/apiCivilCase/', newCivil).success(successCallback)
         .error(errorCallback);
             console.log(newCivil);
};
```

Code that i am trying to get working

```
(function () {
angular.module('lawfirm').factory('CivilPost', function ($http) {
    return {

        post: function (newCivil) {
            return $http.post('/api/apiCivilCase/' +  newCivil);
        }
    };
  });
})();

$scope.addCivilCase = function (newCivil) {
    CivilPost.post(newCivil).success(successCallback)
         .error(errorCallback);
    console.log(newCivil);
};
```

Comment: In the `$http.post()` in the code you're trying to get working, you're appending `newCivil` to the url rather than passing it in as the second argument like you do in the code that works. Could that be the problem?

Comment: that was the problem. thanks. put it in a response so i can give you credit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `$http.post()` in the code you're trying to get working, you're appending `newCivil` to the URL, but you should be passing it in as the second argument like you do in the code that works.